# WordPress arabic permalinks

Tags: wordpress, localization, arabic, permalinks

I'm creating an arabic blog, using the arabic version of wordpress, but when I set the permalink configuration to use the post name, I get a not found error message with similar text to:

```
The requested URL /Ø³ÙŠØ¨Ø³/ was not found on this server.
```

Does anybody have any clues ?

Comment: does all your theme / plugin files and DB UTF-8 ?? Your server ?

Comment: I double checked the Database, for the themes, I'm using the default one 2011 and no plugins

Comment: do you have this : “define(’DB_CHARSET’, ‘utf-8‘);”  in your wp-config ? and also, what collition do you have in the DB ?

Comment: sorry for my late answer, yes I have that line as: define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8'); and I have define('DB_COLLATE', ''); and one more thing is that its working on my local host just fine !

Comment: that was exactly my question, what collition you have on the DB on the production server ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

and thanks for your support to me :)

I have solved my problem, and what was going wrong is my .htaccess file, when installing an arabic wordpress blog locally, I noticed that it was working very well, so I made a comparaison and I noticed that by local .htaccess has content when the other doesn't.

So what solved my problem is putting the following code in my website .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
 # END WordPress
```